# Google Maps API v3 javascript Markers don't always load

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps-api-3, markers

I am creating a site that uses a database in the background to track markers on a javascript google maps api. For some reason when I log in to my site and it redirects to the maps page it will load the map but no markers. Then if I refresh, the markers will show up. I didn't have the problem before until I moved it to a different site but all of the links work so it isn't a problem with links as far as I can tell. Code is below...kinda messy so I apologize.

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:login.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 92.5% }
    </style>
    <title>Map from Database</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../Desktop/kevskans/login/favicon.ico">
   <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAQeeCMHUHY9w5N5J-usSNISMRs3WsMuwk&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../Desktop/kevskans/login/favicon.ico">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">

    var customIcons = {
      "8 Yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "10 Yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "15 Yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "20 Yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_black.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "25 Yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "30 Yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "8 yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "10 yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "15 yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "20 yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_black.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "25 yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "30 yard": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "8 Yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "10 Yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "15 Yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "20 Yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_black.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "25 Yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "30 Yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "8 yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "10 yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "15 yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "20 yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_black.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "25 yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      "30 yards": {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }



    };



    function load() {

        var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

if(navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  }
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  else {
    browserSupportFlag = false;
    handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag == true) {
      alert("Geolocation service failed.");
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(40.797559 , -89.196791);
    } else {
      alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation.");
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(40.797559 , -89.196791);
    }
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
  }

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
          var dumpsterID = markers[i].getAttribute("dumpsterID");
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var parsedaddress = address.split(' ').join('+');
          var startlocation = initialLocation;
          var size = markers[i].getAttribute("size");
          var pic = markers[i].getAttribute("pic");      
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var thing2 = "<a href='http://maps.apple.com/?daddr="+parsedaddress+"&saddr="+startlocation+"'>"+address+"</a>";
          var thing = "<a href='update.php?id="+id+"'>Edit/Delete Entry</a>";
          var page = "map.php";
          var html = "<b> Customer: </b>" + name + "<br/><b>ID: </b>" + dumpsterID  + "<br/><b>Phone: </b><a href='tel:" + phone + "'>"+phone+"</a><br/><b>Address: </b><br/>" + thing2 + "<br/><b>Size: </b>" + size + "<br/>" + thing + "<br/> <a href='"+pic+"'><img height='30' width='30' src='"+pic+"' /></a>";
          var icon = customIcons[size] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }


    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;


      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">


    <button onclick="window.location.href='adddumpster.php'">Add Dumpster</button>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='list_records.php'">Show List of Dumpsters</button>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='logout.php'">Log Out</button>
  <p></p>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form action="this.form.action" id="querybysize" method="post">
<td class="formtext">Query By Size:</td>
<td><select name="size" id="size" onchange="this.form.action=this.value">
    <option value="map.php">All</option>
    <option value="8yardmap.php">8 Yard</option>
    <option value="10yardmap.php">10 Yard</option>
    <option value="15yardmap.php">15 Yard</option>
    <option value="20yardmap.php">20 Yard</option>
    <option value="25yardmap.php">25 Yard</option>
    <option value="30yardmap.php">30 Yard</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Query By Size">
</td>

</form>
</table>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: And half the time it works. Right now I'm logging out and trying again and there's no problem.

Comment: what are you trying to do? i dont see any google maps marker related code here

Comment: The marker code is under the download URL function because it is pulling from a database.

"var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow"

The problem isn't with the marker. In the debugger window it all revolves around whether or not "initialLocation" is defined and for some reason it doesn't always define it. I have been working on the code and I will edit it now.

Comment: this is very vauge and unclear

Comment: The idea is to have the current location stored. Whether for the center of the map or for the purpose of getting directions but this needs to be loaded when all the markers are done in the loop from the database. The problem is that for some reason(not sure why, it works sometimes and not others) initialLocation isn't always defined even though I have set it to be defined in the if statement but then also in the else statement. When it isn't defined it prevents the markers from loading somehow.

Comment: try placing your custom script after `map-canvas`.. since its appearing sometimes and sometimes not it could be due to async loading

Comment: It does it much less often than before now but I still periodically get the "initialLocation" is not defined message

Answer (score 3):

remove the `onload()` function from the body tag and add it at the end of the body

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(onload);
</script>
```